# R: How to detect and plot polygons edges from X Y data frame

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame that contains grid data, with columns corresponding to XY coordinates and a factor "value". 
I would like to detect areas with the same 'value' and plot there edges.

**An example of my data:**

```
dat = melt(volcano[26:40, 26:40])
dat$value=factor(round(dat$value/10))
dat[dat$X1==12 & dat$X2==6,"value"]=NA
dat[dat$X1==13 & dat$X2==6,"value"]=NA
dat=dat[7:nrow(dat),]
head(dat)
```

**My plot:**

```
library(ggplot2)
p=ggplot(dat) +
  geom_tile(aes(x=X1, y=X2, fill=value))+geom_text(aes(x=X1, y=X2, label=value))
p
```

[image: Look at my plot]

My attempt would be to use `p+geom_polygon(data = polys, aes(x = x , y = y , group = id),size=1, color = "black")`, but i'm struggling with the step consisting to get 'polys': the coordinates of edges points. This data frame should like this:

```
id  x  y
1 0.5 1.5
1 1.5 1.5
1 2.5 1.5
1 2.5 2.5
1 1.5 2.5
1 0.5 2.5
1 0.5 1.5
2  2.5  1.5
2  3.5  1.5
2  4.5  1.5
2  5.5  1.5
...
```

with x and y that are the coordinates of the corners of the tiles that i'm looking for, and 'id' the grouping factor for the different polygons. For example id=1 corresponds to the little purple rectangle ine the left bottom corner.

Any idea, to automatically detect these edges points for each area, based on "value" column ?

Thanks